# identifying nodes of a tree in gwt

Tags: gwt, tree

I have a tree widget and I am adding treeitems and several sub nodes to this treeitems dynamically on a click of a button.

I am using addtreeitem () method.
For example I have created a tree which has a level 1.
Level 1 inturn has three level 2s.

And now I have to add a level 3 to the first level 2. As I am doing this dynamically, level 3 is getting added to the last level 2.

How can I identify each node distinctly?
As per my requirement,  I can have any number of nodes like this. There is no limit.

On the click of the same button, I have to properly identify under which treeitem I am supposed to add a child item.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `TreeItem#setUserObject` method to associate tree items with some data. It can be an object from your data model, or it can be a simple String. Something like:

```
treeItem.setUserObject("shoes");
```

or

```
treeItem.setUserObject(ProductCategory.SHOES);
```

Then you traverse the Tree and use `TreeItem#getUserObject` method to identify each item.